How to Ensure Owner Authorization Check with userId in Header and JWT in .NET Web API
I'm working on a .NET Web API where users can register, create profiles, and perform various actions like posting content. I’ve implemented JWT authorization, and I want to make sure that only the owner of the data (e.g., user posts) can access it.
To elaborate on "Owner":
Let’s say I have an endpoint like posts/{userId}. I want to prevent a user with userId = 1 from accessing posts/2, where the post belongs to a different user (user with id 2). If the userId in the JWT (sub claim) doesn’t match the owner of the post, I want to return 403 Forbidden.
What I've Done So Far:
I know the sub claim in JWT contains the userId, and I’ve successfully extracted that for ownership validation.
But, instead of relying on the userId being scattered throughout the request (e.g., route parameters, query strings, or body), I’m considering requiring the userId in the headers for every request. This would simplify ownership checks because the userId would always be in one consistent place—the header.
My Approach:
I plan to pass the userId in a custom header (e.g., X-User-Id) and then compare it with the sub claim from the JWT to ensure they match. If they don’t, I would return a 403 Forbidden response to prevent unauthorized access.
Code Example and I use this attribute in API controller.
public class OwnerAuthorizationFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        var userIdFromToken = context.HttpContext.User.FindFirst("sub")?.Value;
        var userIdFromHeader = context.HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-User-Id"].ToString();

        if (userIdFromToken == null || userIdFromHeader != userIdFromToken)
        {
            context.Result = new ForbidResult();
        }
    }
}

My Questions:
Is this approach (requiring userId in the header) a good practice?
It simplifies the checking process by avoiding lots of conditional logic to find userId in different places like route parameters or request bodies.
I know it introduces duplication since userId is already in the JWT, but I’m trying to balance simplicity and security.
Should I require any additional data in the header?
Besides the userId, is there any other relevant data I should consider passing in the header for authorization?
What’s the best way to handle owner authorization dynamically?
I’m looking for a dynamic and flexible solution where the userId could come from different parts of the request, but I prefer to streamline it in one place. I’ve come across role-based and policy-based approaches, but they seem to add complexity when trying to find userId in every request.
I’ve looked through some other posts on StackOverflow, but I haven’t found a solution that meets my need for a dynamic yet simplified ownership check.

Passing the userId in a custom header and validating it against a claim included in your JWT is not a secure way to protect your API.
Since you rely on the X-User-Id header, you trust the client will always send the correct userId. Even though you're validating the X-User-Id against the claim in the JWT, it still opens up the possibility for someone to misuse your API by manipulating the request.
The best and most secure practice would be to rely on the JWT token itself. Simply include the userId in the token.
Besides, the JWT token is required for authentication. Why rely on both the token and a Header?
Now to address the issue you're having with "owners".
In the example you gave you have a simple endpoint: posts/{userId}.
In your case where you want to restrict a user to accessing this resource only for themselves, you have a couple of options.

Validate the provided userId matches the one in the JWT token (which is safe to do in this context). You could use Filters to implement this on a more global scale. You can read more on Filters in the documentation.
Read the userId from the token, instead of endpoint parameters. Change the endpoint to e.g. posts/user. This way a user cannot access other users' posts by default.

Hope this helps!

userId is already in the token. But how can I verify if the user is the owner? I have updated the question to provide more details and clarify the issue.

Updated my answer according to the additional information your provided.

To implement Filters, I need to check if userId is present in various places like route parameters, query strings, or request bodies. This involves writing a lot of if/else checks, which I’m not very confident about as it makes the code feel repetitive and hard to maintain.
Is there a way to simplify or centralize this ownership validation process without having to write multiple if/else statements for each possible location of the userId in the request?

That depends on the cases where you need to validate ownership of something and how much they differ from each other. Going off of the example you gave this is the way to go about it. You can also stick to one way of providing a userId. That can help in avoiding the if/else checks.
